# Shell read redundant new line character

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a text file:

```
A1   A2
B1   B2
```

I use the script to read the values one by one

```
cat $TXT | while read FILE
do
DATA1=`(echo $FILE | cut -d' ' -f1)`
DATA2=`(echo $FILE | cut -d' ' -f2)`
done
```

However DATA2 will read the extra \n character
example: DATA2 = A2\n.

How can I read the data without getting the extra character?

Thanks very much.

Comment: The immediate problem is that `echo` introduces a newline. You could use `printf` instead, but John Zwink's answer is much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while read DATA1 DATA2 REST
do
    # DATA1 and DATA2 are already set now
done < "$TXT"
```

This has the added advantage of spawning several fewer processes *per line of input*.  Namely, my way spawns zero processes, whereas yours spawns something like 4N + 1.

Comment: It's simple and smart. Thank you.

Comment: If you like my answer, you can "accept" it by selecting the checkmark just below the vote up/down arrows on the left.  Welcome to StackOverflow.